# How to set constraint relationship to view, not subviews programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, anchor

I am trying to setup a couple of views programmatically. On my main view I add two subviews, one anchored to the top and one to the bottom:

```
//Button View
        view.addSubview(buttonsLabel)
        buttonsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        buttonsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonsLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        buttonsLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: -20).isActive = true


//Calculator View
        calcLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        view.addSubview(calcLabel)

        calcLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        calcLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        calcLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        calcLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        //calcLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        calcLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: -40).isActive = true
```

This works fine, both views are 50% of the frame height (minus the constants) and both are shown (one at the top, one at the bottom). But when I try to add a third view, which is 75% of the frames height and which should be placed on top of the other two views, the layout is destroyed and everything is moved almost outside of the frame.

I am trying to anchor the third view to the bottom again:

```
    thirdView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    view.addSubview(thirdView)

    thirdView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    thirdView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    thirdView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    thirdView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
```

This is how everything should look like (left the two views, right the third view on top:

[image]

Am I doing the anchors and constraints right (or whats abetter way) and how to add the constraint for the third view, so that it is 75% of the frames height and placed like in the image on top of everything.

Comment: `thirdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`?

Comment: [RjC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6852849/rjc) did @beyowulf or my solution correct the problem?

Comment: Thanks that was the reason it didn't work the way it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks good the problem is else where, check the view hierarchy in the debugger to see which constraint(s) failed, perhaps you forgot `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` as [beyowulf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5442445/beyowulf) commented. you should be using constants as well, this makes code much more maintainable.

here is my implementation:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    //MARK: - SubViews
    let topHalfView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        return view
    }()

    let bottomHalfView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        return view
    }()

    let threeQuarterView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return view
    }()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //add, layout subviews with 9+ constraints
        setupViews()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func setupViews() {
        self.view.addSubview(topHalfView)
        self.view.addSubview(bottomHalfView)
        self.view.addSubview(threeQuarterView)

        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let spacing:CGFloat = 12
        let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height - spacing


        topHalfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        topHalfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        topHalfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
        topHalfView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewHeight * 0.5).isActive = true

        bottomHalfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topHalfView.bottomAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        bottomHalfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        bottomHalfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
        bottomHalfView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewHeight * 0.5).isActive = true

        threeQuarterView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        threeQuarterView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        threeQuarterView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
        threeQuarterView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.height * 0.75).isActive = true
    }

}
```

The View hierarchy:

[image: The View hierarchy]